# Azure Log Analytics - Query Application Insight Custom Metrics

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

I have an Azure Application Insight component and separate Log Analytics component which pulls data from App Insight. Inside Log Analytics portal, Using Log Analytics query language (power query), I can get Application Insight Traces and Custom Events.

Custom Events in last 24H

customEvents
| where timestamp >= ago(24h)
| order by timestamp desc

Traces in last 24H

traces
| where timestamp >= ago(24h)
| order by timestamp desc

But I cannot read custom metrics I have created. I am not a query language expert. Can someone please tell me, is there a way to query that please?

Answer (score 0):

if the custom metrics were sent along with events/traces (like `trackEvent(name, properties, metrics)`, they'd be in the `customMeasurements` property in the `customEvents` or `traces` tables.

```
customEvents | where timestamp >= ago(24h) 
| project timestamp, name, customMeasurements
| order by timestamp desc
```

if the custom metrics were sent as their own "events" via `trackMetric(name, value, properties)`, then you'd look in the `customMetrics` table

```
customMetrics | where timestamp >= ago(24h) | order by timestamp desc`
```